# pass session variables from one page to another

Tags: javascript, php, session-variables

i have a php page that is a sort of submition form with 3 dropdown sections, that have to send the selections from the dropdowns when you click a button. The form is as follows:

```
<div class="statsValPlate">
            <label>Main Score</label>
            <select name="scoreSelect">
                <option value="301">301</option>
                <option value="501">501</option>
                <option value="701">701</option>
                <option value="1001">1001</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="statsValPlate">
            <label>Legs Format</label>
            <select name="legSelect">
                <option value="3">2 of 3</option>
                <option value="5">3 of 5</option>
                <option value="7">4 of 7</option>
                <option value="9">5 of 9</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="statsValPlate">
            <label>Sets Format</label>
            <select name="setSelect ">
                <option value="3">2 of 3</option>
                <option value="5">3 of 5</option>
                <option value="7">4 of 7</option>
                <option value="9">5 of 9</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <form method="get" action="scoreboard.php">
            <button id="submit" name ="submit" class="push_button red">Start Game</a><br>
        </form>

<?php

        $_SESSION['gameScore'] = $_POST['scoreSelect'];
        $_SESSION['legScore'] = $_POST['legSelect'];
        $_SESSION['setScore'] = $_POST['setSelect'];

?>
```

and i want for instance the selection of the first form has to show up as a label value here:

```
<label class="scorePlate" id="num1" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['gameScore']?>">
                            <!--<?php echo $_SESSION["player1Score"]?>-->
                            <script>
                                document.write(new_score_player_1);
                            </script>
                        </label>
```

but for some reason it doesn't work. What's the problem

Comment: when you submit your given page it goes to `scoreboard.php` so how to set `$_SESSION` in that page?

Answer (score 0):

First, start the session - [session_start()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php).

Second, put all those selects inside the form. When they are outside the form, the values selected won't be sent on form submission.

Second, make the form's method **POST**, not GET.

Your code should look something like this:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if (isset($_POST['submit']) {
        $_SESSION['gameScore'] = $_POST['scoreSelect'];
        $_SESSION['legScore'] = $_POST['legSelect'];
        $_SESSION['setScore'] = $_POST['setSelect'];
    }
?>

<form method="POST" action="scoreboard.php">
    <div class="statsValPlate">
        <label>Main Score</label>
        <select name="scoreSelect">
            <option value="301">301</option>
            <option value="501">501</option>
            <option value="701">701</option>
            <option value="1001">1001</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="statsValPlate">
        <label>Legs Format</label>
        <select name="legSelect">
            <option value="3">2 of 3</option>
            <option value="5">3 of 5</option>
            <option value="7">4 of 7</option>
            <option value="9">5 of 9</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="statsValPlate">
        <label>Sets Format</label>
        <select name="setSelect ">
            <option value="3">2 of 3</option>
            <option value="5">3 of 5</option>
            <option value="7">4 of 7</option>
            <option value="9">5 of 9</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <button id="submit" name ="submit" class="push_button red">Start Game</a><br>
</form>
```

And on the other page:

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>
<label class="scorePlate" id="num1" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['gameScore']; ?>">
    <!--<?php echo $_SESSION["player1Score"]?>-->
    <script>
        document.write(new_score_player_1);
    </script>
</label>
```

Comment: well it didn't work, whether i start the session or not in these pages, it just doesn't work